# Why is removeclass not working when div is collapsed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, removeclass

here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcx0t0fh/)

why when a div is clicked from another div does the arrow not appear back when the other div has collapsed? i have it set up so when the div does not have the class 'clicked' it then removes the class 'arrowhide' but it when you do the above it doesn't seem to remove the 'arrowhide' even though the div no longer has the class 'clicked' here is my code...

```
$(function timelinetiles() {
   $('.timelineTile').click(function (evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    $('.selected').children().not(this).removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');

    if ($('.selected').children().hasClass("clicked")) {
        $('.details').addClass('show');
    }

    if ($('.timelineTile').hasClass("clicked")) {
        $(this).children('.arrow').addClass('arrowhide');
    } else {
        $('.arrow').removeClass('arrowhide');
    }


    if ($('.selected').children().hasClass("clicked")) {
        $(this).children('.header').height(430);
    } else {
        $('.header').height(80);
    }


});
});

$(document).click(function () {
$('.timelineTile').removeClass('clicked');
$('.details').removeClass('show');
$('.arrow').removeClass('arrowhide');
});
```

Comment: try wrapping that inside document.ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line 4 also needs to remove the arrowhide class, like this:

```
$('.selected').children().not(this).removeClass('clicked')
.children('.arrow').removeClass('arrowhide');
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mcx0t0fh/2/

Alternatively, you could do away with the arrowhide business, and change your .arrow.arrowhide CSS rule to .clicked .arrow

Alternative fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mcx0t0fh/4/